# nftables Rules for ProxyChains-over-Tor

Tags: iptables, proxy, nftables, http-proxy, tor

I am trying to configure nftables rules for ProxyChains-over-Tor, so that:

```
My system --> Tor SOCKS5 proxy --> HTTP proxy --> Internet
```

- My system can only communicate with Tor SOCKS5 proxy
- Tor SOCKS5 proxy can only communicate with my system and the HTTP proxy
- The HTTP proxy can only communicate with Tor SOCKS5 proxy and the Internet
- The Internet can only communicate with the HTTP proxy

---

I see from [this article](https://sorsasampo.gitlab.io/post/2018-01-10-limiting-linux-user-to-tor-connections-only/) that the correct nftables rules to block everything except Tor access is:

```
chain output {
    ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 9050 accept
    reject
}
```

That works for Tor alone, however, it gets a bit confusing when a further proxy is involved.

---

Currently I have the following nftables rules for this scenario:

```
chain output {
    ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 9050 accept
    ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 9050 tcp sport {proxy_port} ip saddr {proxy_ip} accept
    reject
}
```

Is this simple change enough to enforce the restrictions mentioned above? Or do I need to introduce a more complex setup with input/forward chains in my rule configuration to prevent my system from communicating directly with the proxy (or directly with the Internet)?

I would appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or example configurations to achieve the correct nftables rules for ProxyChains-over-Tor. Thank you in advance!